# Modifying variable from a derived class

Tags: c#

I've looked around but couldn't find a concrete answer to my question.

This is a part of my abstract class Account  I am interested in :

```
 public abstract class Account
 {

 private decimal balance;

 public decimal Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return this.balance;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Balance can't be negative");
            }
            balance = value;
        }
    }
 protected Account(decimal balance)
    {
        this.Balance = balance;
    }
 }
```

Now I have a derived class called DepositAccount which works direclty with the Balance property,using a Withdraw() method from my IWithdraw interface.

```
public class DepositAccount : Account, IWithdraw
    {
        public DepositAccount(decimal balance)
            : base(balance)
        {

        }
        public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            if (amount > this.Balance)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Not enough balance!");
            }
            this.Balance -= Balance;
        }
    }
```

My question is how to best implement the Balance property in the base Account class?

I only want derived classes(those accounts that will be able to withdraw or deposit money) to be able to modify it(thus the protected set).

Shall I set the property to protected rather than public or keep only the setter protected?

Comment: Why would you make the getter protected? Any reason other classes should not read the Balance?

Comment: Depends on whether or not reading the balance is allowed publicly or not. This is a design decision question.

Comment: If you want anyone to be able to read balance, but only derived classes to be able to set it, you have it right.  Making the getter protected would only allow derived classes to read balance.

Comment: Perhaps you should think about making `decimal Balance { get; }` a virtual property. You should think about `Account`s that allow for negative Balances. For example Mortgage accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are syntactic sugar to make accessors easier and elegant to implement, but they still compile into regular methods.

How you would solve your issue if you would be talking about methods instead of properties? I guess you would end with the same solution: what modifies `Balance` would be protected and retrieving its value would be `public`.

If you want to publicly access `Balance`, leave it `public`, otherwise use `protected`.